# roboto font not working in css

Tags: css, xhtml, font-face, webfonts, google-webfonts

I've CSS and XHTML files. I've downloaded all the ROBOTO fonts and put it in my "webapps/fonts/" folder.

In my XHTML i mentioned the CSS Path,

```
'<link href="../css/tab_ux.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />'
```

AND my CSS file have styles like,

```
@font-face {
   font-family:roboto-bold;
   src: url('../fonts/Roboto-Bold.tff') @ttf;
}

.UX_FontClass {
   font-family: roboto-bolditalic !important;
   font-size : 25px !important;
}
```

also mentioned XHTML in `OutputText as styleClass="UX_FontClass "`

Even though font is not working in any browser. What i did wrong with my code? OR Anything i missed out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using custom font so you need to add a few font type format as well; like `ttf`, `eot` and `svg` for iphone, ipad devices.

> Note: Some browsers supports different font type that's why you need
>   `ttf`,`svg` or `eot`.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    src: url('Roboto-ThinItalic-webfont.eot');
    src: url('Roboto-ThinItalic-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('Roboto-ThinItalic-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('Roboto-ThinItalic-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('Roboto-ThinItalic-webfont.svg#RobotoThinItalic') format('svg'); (under the Apache Software License). 
    font-weight: 200;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

Remember after that you need to add this code in class `UX_FontClass`

```
.UX_FontClass {font-family: 'Roboto', Arial, Helevtica, sans-serif; }
```

Comment: so i want to download .eot,.woff & .svg format roboto fonts and placed  in same folder right?

Comment: no, there are few online tool are available which will generate all font type. you just need to keep same font type under same folder.

Comment: this tool you can use, it will give you all font  formats. https://everythingfonts.com/font-face or http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

Comment: If my solution works for you then you may close this answer by accepting it.

Answer (score 6):

You should use google fonts, its really easy to use.

https://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Robot

example

```
<head>
 <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
<p style="font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;">Hello World</p>
</body>
```

Comment: if you don't trust the link like the other guys, just google 'google fonts roboto'

Comment: Just remember the single ticks around the font name, that was my problem...

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Google fonts?

Place in the header of your html:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100,300,100italic,300italic,400italic,500italic,500,700,700italic,900,900italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Use in your css:

```
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
```

Comment: for a security purpose we don't want this web link. can u suggest any other way to achieve this.

Comment: @user3114967 *security purpose* - If you're really concerned about it, use https.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in defining a font named `roboto-bold` in the @font-face clause, but trying to use a font named `roboto-bolditalic` later on. That is not the same family!

Solution: make sure the names match.
You probably meant

```css
font-family:'roboto-bold'; font-style:italic;
```

or, since you're defining the size too, you could use the `font` shorthand

```css
font:italic 25px 'roboto-bold';
```

And there's no need for the `!important`.

Answer (score -2):

1. its really easy to use in css.

   @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:700,400,500,300);

Comment: Sir, OP doesn't want to use google font library due to security reasons. I don't know how you answer is different than others offering same solution.

Comment: @KheemaPandey and still got upvoted. SO users are not reading OP comments for sure!

Comment: The OP did add the [google-webfonts] tag to the question, which might have contributed to the confusion.